# Principal Propagation is not working in the latest version of SAP Cloud SDK

Tags: sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-sdk

**It works in SAP Cloud SDK Version 3.7.0 to 3.10.0 but failed in the latest version from 3.11.0 to 3.13.0.**

I have two applications deployed on SAP Cloud Platform. One is cloud java application based on SAP Cloud SDK using destination which is configured with Principal Propagation. The other is app router.

All related configuration of Principal Propagation are all finished in Cloud Connector and backend on-premise system. We also set up our own identity provider in SAP Cloud Platform.

Let me introduce what we want to achieve.

User login to cloud application using our own IDP from app router and then get some data from S4 on-premise system using the same user (different from the technical user in Basic authentication) configured in destination.

For more details please refer to https://blogs.sap.com/2017/07/13/part-2-how-to-use-the-sap-cloud-platform-connectivity-and-the-cloud-connector-in-the-cloud-foundry-environment/

What I did in java application to invoke billing document from S4 system.

```
public List<BillingDocument> getAllBillingdocuments() throws BusinessException {

        ResilienceConfiguration resilienceConfig = ResilienceConfiguration.of(MyBillingDocumentService.class)
                                                                                 .cacheConfiguration(CacheConfiguration.of(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                                                                                 .withoutParameters());  // Cache key

        List<BillingDocument> billingDocuments;
        try {
            billingDocuments = ResilienceDecorator.executeCallable(() -> bdService.getAllBillingDocument()
                                                                                  .execute(DestinationUtil.getHttpDestinationS4XSSO()),
                                                                                       resilienceConfig);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw BusinessException.convert(e);
        }
        return billingDocuments;
    }
```

I will leave out the configuration of app router. I promise it is correct.

The problem is user can login to cloud java application via app router using our own IDP, but when he/she wanted to get data from S4 on-premise system by the below url, the error always occurred.

https://****.cfapps.***.hana.ondemand.com/test311/billingdocument

The detailed error log from java application:

```
2020-02-17T06:01:22.948+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2020-02-17T06:01:22.945Z","written_ts":277856327935563,"tenant_id":"-","component_type":"application","component_id":"***","space_name":"***","component_name":"TestVer3.11_service","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","organization_name":"-","space_id":"240338f7-479a-402f-bb31-f3aaf5c90406","container_id":"10.0.137.28","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.cache.metadata.GuavaMetadataCache","thread":"cloudsdk-resilience-0","level":"ERROR","categories":[],"msg":"Error occurred while populating metadata: ","stacktrace":["com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler$ErpODataException: The endpoint responded with HTTP error code 401.nnFull error message: nSSO token validation failed. Make sure trust is configured correctly in the cloud connector to enable principal propagation, if token has not expired yet.","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.createException(ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.java:117)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.createError(ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.java:97)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.createError(ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.java:33)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.internal.ODataConnectivityUtil.checkHttpStatus(ODataConnectivityUtil.java:219)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.cache.metadata.GuavaMetadataCache.getEdm(GuavaMetadataCache.java:239)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.cache.metadata.GuavaMetadataCache.getEdm(GuavaMetadataCache.java:156)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.loadMetadata(ODataQuery.java:379)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.loadEntriesFromDestination(ODataQuery.java:310)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.internalExecute(ODataQuery.java:253)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.execute(ODataQuery.java:151)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.execute(ODataQuery.java:135)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.FluentHelperRead.execute(FluentHelperRead.java:250)","tat com.bosch.test.service.MyBillingDocumentService.lambda$getAllBillingdocuments$0(MyBillingDocumentService.java:55)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextCallable.call(ThreadContextCallable.java:247)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.AbstractThreadContextExecutor.execute(AbstractThreadContextExecutor.java:293)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.resilience4j.Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.lambda$decorateCallable$1(Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.java:107)","tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)","tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)","tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)","tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836)"] }
2020-02-17T06:01:23.168+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "written_at":"2020-02-17T06:01:23.167Z","written_ts":277856550010598,"tenant_id":"-","component_type":"application","component_id":"***","space_name":"***","component_name":"TestVer3.11_service","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","organization_name":"-","space_id":"240338f7-479a-402f-bb31-f3aaf5c90406","container_id":"10.0.137.28","type":"log","logger":"com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.cache.metadata.GuavaMetadataCache","thread":"cloudsdk-resilience-0","level":"ERROR","categories":[],"msg":"Error occurred while populating metadata: ","stacktrace":["com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler$ErpODataException: The endpoint responded with HTTP error code 401.nnFull error message: nSSO token validation failed. Make sure trust is configured correctly in the cloud connector to enable principal propagation, if token has not expired yet.","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.createException(ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.java:117)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.createError(ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.java:97)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.createError(ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.java:33)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.internal.ODataConnectivityUtil.checkHttpStatus(ODataConnectivityUtil.java:219)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.cache.metadata.GuavaMetadataCache.getEdm(GuavaMetadataCache.java:239)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.cache.metadata.GuavaMetadataCache.getEdm(GuavaMetadataCache.java:156)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.loadMetadata(ODataQuery.java:379)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.loadEntriesFromDestination(ODataQuery.java:310)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.internalExecute(ODataQuery.java:253)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.retryExecuteWithCompleteUrl(ODataQuery.java:172)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.execute(ODataQuery.java:157)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.execute(ODataQuery.java:135)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.FluentHelperRead.execute(FluentHelperRead.java:250)","tat com.bosch.test.service.MyBillingDocumentService.lambda$getAllBillingdocuments$0(MyBillingDocumentService.java:55)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextCallable.call(ThreadContextCallable.java:247)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.AbstractThreadContextExecutor.execute(AbstractThreadContextExecutor.java:293)","tat com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.resilience4j.Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.lambda$decorateCallable$1(Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.java:107)","tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)","tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)","tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)","tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836)"] }
2020-02-17T06:01:23.171+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.resilience.ResilienceRuntimeException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.resilience.ResilienceRuntimeException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.exception.ThreadContextExecutionException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataException: Unable to fetch the metadata : Failed to execute OData Metadata request.
2020-02-17T06:01:23.172+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.resilience4j.Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.lambda$null$2(Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.java:123)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.172+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at io.vavr.control.Try.onFailure(Try.java:659)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.172+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.resilience4j.Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.lambda$decorateCallable$3(Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.java:122)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.172+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.resilience.ResilienceDecorationStrategy.executeCallable(ResilienceDecorationStrategy.java:184)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.172+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.resilience.ResilienceDecorator.executeCallable(ResilienceDecorator.java:197)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.172+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.bosch.test.service.MyBillingDocumentService.getAllBillingdocuments(MyBillingDocumentService.java:54)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.172+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.bosch.test.controllers.MyBillingDocumentController.getAllBillingDocuments(MyBillingDocumentController.java:32)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.172+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.172+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.172+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.172+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.172+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.172+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.172+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.172+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.172+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.172+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.172+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.172+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.172+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.173+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.173+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.173+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.173+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.173+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.173+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.173+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.173+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.173+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.173+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestAccessorFilter.lambda$doFilter$1(RequestAccessorFilter.java:71)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.173+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.AbstractThreadContextExecutor.lambda$execute$0(AbstractThreadContextExecutor.java:317)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.173+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextCallable.call(ThreadContextCallable.java:247)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.173+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.AbstractThreadContextExecutor.execute(AbstractThreadContextExecutor.java:319)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.173+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestAccessorFilter.doFilter(RequestAccessorFilter.java:71)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.173+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.173+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.173+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.173+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.173+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.173+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.173+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.174+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.174+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.174+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.174+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.174+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.174+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.174+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.174+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.174+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.174+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:180)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.174+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.174+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.174+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.174+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.174+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.174+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.174+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.174+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.174+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.174+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.174+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.174+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.175+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.175+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.175+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.175+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.175+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.175+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.175+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.175+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.175+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.175+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.175+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.175+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.175+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.175+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.175+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.175+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.175+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.175+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.175+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.175+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.175+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.175+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.175+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.176+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.176+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:747)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.176+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.176+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.176+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.176+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.176+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.176+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.176+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.176+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.176+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.176+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.176+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.resilience.ResilienceRuntimeException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.exception.ThreadContextExecutionException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataException: Unable to fetch the metadata : Failed to execute OData Metadata request.
2020-02-17T06:01:23.176+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.resilience4j.DefaultCachingDecorator.lambda$decorateCallable$0(DefaultCachingDecorator.java:124)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.176+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at io.vavr.control.Try.of(Try.java:75)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.176+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at io.vavr.control.Try.ofCallable(Try.java:105)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.176+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.resilience4j.Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.lambda$decorateCallable$3(Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.java:118)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.176+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   ... 95 more
2020-02-17T06:01:23.176+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.exception.ThreadContextExecutionException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataException: Unable to fetch the metadata : Failed to execute OData Metadata request.
2020-02-17T06:01:23.177+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.AbstractThreadContextExecutor.execute(AbstractThreadContextExecutor.java:299)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.177+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.resilience4j.Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.lambda$decorateCallable$1(Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.java:107)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.177+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.177+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.177+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.177+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   ... 1 more
2020-02-17T06:01:23.177+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataException: Unable to fetch the metadata : Failed to execute OData Metadata request.
2020-02-17T06:01:23.177+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.loadEntriesFromDestination(ODataQuery.java:312)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.177+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.internalExecute(ODataQuery.java:253)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.177+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.retryExecuteWithCompleteUrl(ODataQuery.java:172)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.177+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.execute(ODataQuery.java:157)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.177+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.execute(ODataQuery.java:135)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.177+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.FluentHelperRead.execute(FluentHelperRead.java:250)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.177+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.bosch.test.service.MyBillingDocumentService.lambda$getAllBillingdocuments$0(MyBillingDocumentService.java:55)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.177+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextCallable.call(ThreadContextCallable.java:247)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.177+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.AbstractThreadContextExecutor.execute(AbstractThreadContextExecutor.java:293)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.177+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   ... 5 more
2020-02-17T06:01:23.177+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler$ErpODataException: The endpoint responded with HTTP error code 401.
2020-02-17T06:01:23.177+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Full error message: 
2020-02-17T06:01:23.177+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR SSO token validation failed. Make sure trust is configured correctly in the cloud connector to enable principal propagation, if token has not expired yet.
2020-02-17T06:01:23.177+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.createException(ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.java:117)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.177+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.createError(ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.java:97)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.178+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.createError(ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.java:33)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.178+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.internal.ODataConnectivityUtil.checkHttpStatus(ODataConnectivityUtil.java:219)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.178+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.cache.metadata.GuavaMetadataCache.getEdm(GuavaMetadataCache.java:239)
2020-02-17T06:01:23.178+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.cache.metadata.GuavaMetadataCache.getEdm(GuavaMetadataCache.java:156)
```

Set default PrincipalPropagationStrategy

```
public static HttpDestination getHttpDestinationS4XSSO() {
        PrincipalPropagationStrategy.setDefaultStrategy(PrincipalPropagationStrategy.COMPATIBILITY);
        Destination destination = DestinationAccessor.getDestination("S4X_HTTP_SSO");
        return destination.asHttp().decorate(DefaultErpHttpDestination::new);
    }
```

Comment: First idea: Reconnect the Cloud Connector with the subaccount.

Comment: Thank you. But it always works for previous version. It might not be the reason.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but have you tried reconnecting Cloud Connector and the subaccount?

Comment: I tested again as you suggested. But I still got the same error. I used the same project(same code) to check between 3.7.0 and 3.13.0. It always works with 3.7.0 but not with 3.13.0.

Comment: Then pls share the Cloud Connector log with us.

Comment: When you‘re saying „I tested again“ do you mean that you reconnected the Cloud Connector and the subaccount?

Comment: Yes, I reconnected Cloud connector and subaccount.

Comment: Relevant error message: `SSO token validation failed. Make sure trust is configured correctly in the cloud connector to enable principal propagation, if token has not expired yet.`

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Pls provide the Cloud Connector log entries.

Comment: I am requesting cloud connector logs from responsible team. Meanwhile, I found that it works in version 3.10.0 and does not in 3.11.0. There are some changes regarding principal propagation in cloud sdk 3.11.0. Could you help to check what is impacted in version 3.11.0?

Comment: Hi Jerry, you're right pointing out that Cloud SDK 3.11.0 introduced some changes concerning principal propagation. However, pls note that the error message `SSO token validation failed. Make sure trust is configured correctly in the cloud connector to enable principal propagation, if token has not expired yet.` does come from a lacking trust configuration in the whole setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

We fixed the reported issue with SAP Cloud SDK `3.16.1`

If possible please update the dependencies accordingly.

---

**Original answer:**

The *SAP Cloud SDK* has adopted the **recommended** option to implement user propagation, see
[SAP Cloud Platform Connectivity: Configure Principal Propagation via User Exchange Token](https://help.sap.com/viewer/cca91383641e40ffbe03bdc78f00f681/Cloud/en-US/39f538ad62e144c58c056ebc34bb6890.html)

However, if the recommended option is not working for you, then a switch to the old practice is possible: the **compatibility** option. Just invoke the following method once in your application code:

```java
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.PrincipalPropagationStrategy;

PrincipalPropagationStrategy.setDefaultStrategy(PrincipalPropagationStrategy.COMPATIBILITY);
```

This will effectively revert the changes, that you are experiencing between version `3.10.0` and `3.11.0`.

---

We have found a potential issue with our implementation from `3.11.0` and onward. Until this is fixed, please try the following quick workaround for resolving a HttpDestination. In the meantime we are working on a fix for the next version to come:

```java
private HttpDestination getHttpDestination( final String destinationName ) {
  Destination destination = DestinationAccessor.tryGetDestination(destinationName).get();

  String url = destination.get("URL", String.class).getOrNull();
  ScpCfHttpDestination.Builder builder = ScpCfHttpDestination.builder(destinationName, url);

  // set properties
  for( String propertyName : destination.getPropertyNames() ) {
    builder.property(propertyName, destination.get(propertyName).getOrNull());
  }

  // add missing token (a workaround as of Cloud SDK 3.11, until fixed)
  String authToken = AuthTokenAccessor.getCurrentToken().getJwt().getToken();
  builder.header("SAP-Connectivity-Authentication", "Bearer " + authToken);

  // decorate optional S/4 destination properties, e.g. sap-client
  return builder.build().decorate(DefaultErpHttpDestination::new);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alexander. I tried the workaround but still got the same error. Is there other places which need to be changed?

Comment: It would be invoked at least once. Invoking it every time, like in your code, is also totally fine.

Comment: Please find my updated answer. If this won't help, then we need to look at the [Apache wire logs](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/logging.html) to understand why the HTTP request is not working.

Comment: Actually we have misunderstandings. The proxy type of Destination I am using is OnPremise. There are only three authentication types I can choose. And now I am using PrincipalPropagation. I also tested it based on your suggestion. It did not work.

Comment: Dear Alexander, Hi Jerry,

seems we're facing quite the same issue. I've posted mine at [How to pass JWT from CAP Java App to SAP Cloud SDK Java backend call](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12998425/how-to-pass-jwt-from-cap-java-app-to-sap-cloud-sdk.html) and a sample repository at [epmbp-consumer-app-java](https://github.com/gregorwolf/epmbp-consumer-app-java). The suggestion to add the JWT token to the headers was not sucessful. So maybe Alexander you can try my sample and suggest a fix.

Comment: Hello Jerry (and Gregor), in my answer I updated the _workaround code_ proposal for `getHttpDestinationS4XSSO`. Now an instance of `ScpCfHttpDestination` will be built instead of previous `DefaultErpHttpDestination`. This should now supply the correct headers. Please try again.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderDümont,
I've updated my sample project [epmbp-consumer-app-java](https://github.com/gregorwolf/epmbp-consumer-app-java) with your suggestions. Unfortunately I'm still not able to get the request through.

Comment: Please find the updated workaround. It took some time to reproduce the issue. Hopefully it enables Principal Propagation for you.

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderDümont! With the latest adjustment it works. You can check my [last commit](https://github.com/gregorwolf/epmbp-consumer-app-java/commit/e5ad6b15ea2efb0cddf15cd7a7fcaea961bed7ab) for the changes that I've applied. Now reading the backend data without issues.

Comment: Great! We'll keep you posted for an officially fixed version.

Comment: Please use latest version of SAP Cloud SDK `3.16.1`. In this release we fixed the issue.

Comment: Dear @AlexanderDümont,
is there anywhere a public example that shows the best way to get the destination with SSO? Maybe you can send a pull request for my repository https://github.com/gregorwolf/epmbp-consumer-app-java?

Answer (score 0):

The error message `SSO token validation failed. Make sure trust is configured correctly in the cloud connector to enable principal propagation, if token has not expired yet.` indicates an outdated/wrong/lacking trust configuration between the Cloud Connector and Cloud Foundry.

Kindly reconsider the trust configuration as per its [official documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/cca91383641e40ffbe03bdc78f00f681/Cloud/en-US/a4ee70f0274248f8bbc7594179ef948d.html), conduct the steps below headline 'Configure Trusted Entities in the Cloud Connector' in particular